# Factoring a smooth map as a function to a linear map

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

I am searching for a reference to the following fact about smooth functions.

If $f \in C^k(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ such that $f(0) = 0$, then there exists $g \in C^{k - 1}(\mathbb{R}^n, \operatorname{Lin}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m))$ such that $$f (x) = g(x)[x].$$

The proof goes through defining
$$
  g(x)[v] := \sum_{\ell= 1}^k \frac{D^\ell f(0)[x, \dotsc, x,v]}{\ell!}+ \Bigl(f(x) - \sum_{\ell=1}^k \frac{D^\ell f(0)[x, \dotsc, x]}{\ell!}\Bigr) \frac{x \cdot v}{\Vert x \Vert^2},
$$
the required smoothness at $0$ follows from the properties of Taylor polynomials.

When $k=1$, this is essentially Carathéodory’s characterisation of derivatives (Ernesto Acosta G. and Cesar Delgado G., *Frechet vs. Caratheodory,*
The American Mathematical Monthly , **101** (1994), 332-338, https://doi.org/10.2307/2975625).